# LinkedIn API for SSO

Tags: linkedin-api

#linkedin #linkedin-api #api LinkedIn APIs
I have created a LinkedIn SSO app, but I am only able to extract two fields from it (name and email). Could you please let me know if there is any way to access more fields such as the profile and company name?

I am only able to get two fields values( Name and Email)